# VSCode "Sync Changes"-Button Giving Bad Object Error

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

Currently, whenever I click the "Sync Changes" button (which I am guessing will push my changes to GitHub) I get an error which directs me to an error that goes:

```
git pull --tags origin master
fatal: bad object refs/desktop.ini
error: https://github.com/kineticneticat/botto.git did not send all necessary objects
```

I have tried looking up about "bad object git" and things like that but because I have no idea what I am doing I don't really know where to put the commands.
Does anyone have any solutions to this? Just saying, this is my first time really fiddling with git/GitHub so I probably will ask some stupid questions.

Edit: I have just realised that even though it talks about a desktop.ini file there is none.
Edit 2: So a `desktop.ini` just reappeared but hasn't fixed anything.

Comment: `refs/desktop.ini` suggests that some errant software created a file named `desktop.ini` in the `refs` subdirectory of the otherwise-hidden `.git` directory that holds the actual repository. Find the software that did this (created `.git/refs/desktop.ini`) and give it a good stern talking-to, because doing that was bad. :-) Seriously, figure out why that happened and make it stop happening.

Comment: The problem is that it is creating the `desktp.ini` in the root folder of the project and I have no idea how to access the `.git` file ( as in instead of it being at `root/.git/refs/desktop.ini` it is at `root/desktop.ini`)

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who is facing this problem:
In my case, and probably @kineticcat case, the software responsible for creating the `desktop.init` files were **Google Drive**.

I resolved the problem and could be able to `git pull` by:

1. First, you need to change Windows explorer settings to show hidden files and system files: https://kb.blackbaud.com/knowledgebase/articles/Article/41890.
   With this, you're able to see the `.git` folder and all `desktop.ini` files.
2. Disable/Close **Google Drive**.
3. Open the `.git` directory in the project folder, search for `desktop.ini` in search bar. Delete all found files.
4. Now run again `git pull` command.

PS: When Google Drive starts again it will recreate the desktop.ini files. So is better to remove the project folder (or at least `.git`) from Google Drive synchronization or whatever software is creating the files.